# How to delete columns from a data.table based on values in column

Tags: r, data.table

### Background

I have some financial data (1.5 years SP500 stocks) that I have manipulated into a wide format using the data.table package. After following the whole data.table course on Datacamp, I'm starting to get a hang of the basics, but after searching for hours I'm at a loss on how to do this.

### The Problem

The data contains columns with financial data for each stock. I need to delete columns that contain two consecutive *NA*s.

My guess is I have to use `rle()`, `lapply()`, to find consecutive values and `DT[,x:= NULL]`) to delete the columns.

I read that `rle()` doesn't work on *NA*s, so I changed them to *Inf* instead.
I just don't know how to combine the functions so that I can efficiently remove a few columns among the 460 that I have.

An answer using `data.table` would be great, but anything that works well is very much appreciated.

Alternatively I would love to know how to remove columns containing at least 1 NA

### Example data

```
> test[1:5,1:5,with=FALSE]
         date     10104     10107     10138     10145
1: 2012-07-02  0.003199       Inf  0.001112 -0.012178
2: 2012-07-03  0.005873  0.006545  0.001428       Inf
3: 2012-07-05       Inf -0.001951 -0.011090       Inf
4: 2012-07-06       Inf -0.016775 -0.009612       Inf
5: 2012-07-09 -0.002742 -0.006129 -0.001294  0.005830
> dim(test)
[1] 377 461
```

### Desired outcome

```
         date     10107     10138
1: 2012-07-02       Inf  0.001112
2: 2012-07-03  0.006545  0.001428
3: 2012-07-05 -0.001951 -0.011090
4: 2012-07-06 -0.016775 -0.009612
5: 2012-07-09 -0.006129 -0.001294
```

PS. This is my first question, I have tried to adhere to the rules, if I need to change anything please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously the issue is finding *consecutive* missing. 
First, create a matrix `TRUE/FALSE` based on missing `NA`. Use that matrix to compare each row to next. Keep columns in original matrix where `colSums == 0`

Try this:

```
Missing.Mat <- apply(test, 2, is.na)
Consecutive.Mat <- Missing.Mat[-nrow(Missing.Mat),] * Missing.Mat[-1,]
Keep.Cols <- colSums(Consecutive.Mat) == 0

test[,Keep.Cols]
```

Comment: to delete columns with at least one `NA` use `Keep.Cols <- colSums(Missing.Ma)==0` instead.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, this is great.

Because I use the data.table package, the last line has to be `test[,Keep.Cols, with=FALSE]`

I was totally missing the point by focussing on only the data.table.

Do I understand it correctly that you make Consecutive.Mat by multiplying offset versions of Missing.Mat, where two consecutive would "overlap"?

Comment: that's right. It does this solution still work for you?

Comment: I think a bit more `data.table`ish version would be something like `setDT(df1)[, names(Filter(isTRUE, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x[-1L] == x[-.N]) == 0)))] ; df1[, names(indx), with = FALSE]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg You should add a separate answer for this one.

Comment: @StevenBeaupré it's just a slight modification of this answer as I simply can't trace any `data.table` syntax around here.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, That is very compact and keeps me from cluttering with extraneous data if this needs to be done on may datasets. I'm assuming df1 would be the name of my data.table right? What does indx point to? thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add `indx <-`. It should be: `indx <- setDT(df1)[, names(Filter(isTRUE, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x[-1L] == x[-.N]) == 0)))] ; df1[, names(indx), with = FALSE]`. And yes, `df1` is your data.

Comment: wrap the code in a `function` and it won't save anything `return(test)`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an `rle` version:

```
dt[, sapply(dt, function(x)
       setDT(rle(is.na(x)))[, sum(lengths > 1 & values) == 0]), with = F]
```

Or replace the `is.na` with `is.infinite` if you like.

Answer (score 2):

To detect and delete columns containing atleast one NA, you can try the following

```
data = data.frame(A=c(1,2,3,4,5), B=c(2,3,4,NA,6), C=c(3,4,5,6,7), D=c(4,5,NA,NA,8))

colsToDelete = lapply(data, FUN = function(x){ sum(is.na(x)) >= 1 })

data.formatted = data[,c(!unlist(colsToDelete))]
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, multiple `NA` entries are acceptable, however, consecutive `NA` entries are not.

Comment: I was trying to answer the alternate part of the question  "Alternatively I would love to know how to remove columns containing at least 1 NA"

Comment: You do realize this is a `data.table` question, right? I can't find any `data.table` syntax around here...

Comment: @DavidArenburg Don't `data.frame` methods work on `data.table` objects?

Comment: @blakeoft not sure what you mean, but if OP was looking for a base R solution I'd guess he wouldn't spend so much time on learning `data.table`. But it seems he is satisfied with a base solution after all....

Comment: @DavidArenburg My point is that I think that functions that take `data.frame` objects as input will work on `data.table` objects. It sounds like the OP learned `data.table` to convert to reshape the data.

Comment: @DavidArenburg . data.table package extends from data.frames, so  as blakeoft mentioned any function which takes data.frame can also work with data.table

Comment: @DavidArenburg, @blakeoft, I'm new to R (writing my thesis) and I did learn data.table to reshape the data.
I'm happy with the base R solution because I am pressed for time, although I would love to know if there is a `data.table` solution. I'll edit the question accordingly.

Comment: @SKG thank you for clearing that out for me. Very new to `data.table`.

Comment: Btw, if you already at it, you could easily vectorise this with just `data[colSums(is.na(data)) == 0]`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with. It calls `rle` on a vector `y` that is `1:length(column)` unless a corresponding element of the column is `Inf`, in which case the corresponding value in y is zero. Then it checks if any of the runs are greater than 1.

```
keep <- c(date = T, apply(dat[, -1], 2,
              function(x) {
                y <- 1:length(x)
                y[!is.finite(x)] <- 0
                return(!any(rle(y)$lengths > 1))
              }))

dat2 <- dat[, keep]
dat2
#         date    X10107    X10138
# 1 2012-07-02       Inf  0.001112
# 2 2012-07-03  0.006545  0.001428
# 3 2012-07-05 -0.001951 -0.011090
# 4 2012-07-06 -0.016775 -0.009612
# 5 2012-07-09 -0.006129 -0.001294
```

Note that the column names are prepended with an "X" by `read.table`.

Now, the dput of the data:

```
dat <- structure(list(date = c("2012-07-02", "2012-07-03", "2012-07-05", 
"2012-07-06", "2012-07-09"), X10104 = c(0.003199, 0.005873, Inf, 
Inf, -0.002742), X10107 = c(Inf, 0.006545, -0.001951, -0.016775, 
-0.006129), X10138 = c(0.001112, 0.001428, -0.01109, -0.009612, 
-0.001294), X10145 = c(-0.012178, Inf, Inf, Inf, 0.00583)), .Names = c("date", 
"X10104", "X10107", "X10138", "X10145"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```